# Is there a difference between the terms statistical learning and machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

Quick question I guess, but is there a perceivable difference between the terms *Statistical Learning* and *Machine Learning*, or is it simply area jargon? I gather the computer scientists like to refer to machine learning while statisticians might refer to statistical learning (no less influenced by the [famous book](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf)).

---

This motif repeats across other questions in the site as well, with many questions like "what's the difference between machine learning and *something else*", but I'd like to have this one specifically answered (with some references if possible) to solve the possible merge of the terms.

This question is rooted in a recent question on meta regarding [The *learning tags](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4525/the-learning-tags), where SL and ML were agreed to be made synonyms ([refer to my answer for some background and what I have gathered on the subject so far](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4543/60613)).

---

Quoting my answer:

> Perphaps the difference is simply cultural, like many discussions in
>   the main site pointed. Consider Stanford, where two courses are
>   taught: [Stats 315a](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/stat315a.html)/[315b](http://web.stanford.edu/class/stats315b/) - Statistical Learning and [CS
>   229](http://cs229.stanford.edu/) - Machine Learning. Apart from being named different and being
>   in different concentrations areas, they also attract different
>   students.
>
> [Tibshirani even shares his views in his page](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/stat315a/CS229vsStat315a) comparing both
>   courses and then both terms:
>
> > Machine learning research focusses more  on low noise situations, eg 
> >     engineering applications like robotics and physical sciences
> >
> > Statistical learning focusses  more on high noise, observational data
> >     like medicine and genomics, and problems where interpretation of the
> >     fitted model is important
> >
> > But more and more overlap in application areas!
>
> ---
>
> [James, G., Witten, D., Hastie, T., & Tibshirani, R. (2013). An introduction to statistical learning (Vol. 6). New York: Springer.](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf)

Comment: Another wrinkle in this is the term _statistical machine learning_, which I've mostly heard used to describe theoretical analysis of machine learning-type algorithms and their foundations (e.g. [this course](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/)). I don't know what intersection that has the other terms (and how consistently it's used itself).